# Are $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ shift-invariant spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a so-called generator $\phi$, we define the shift-invariant space in the following way:
$$V^2(\phi)=\left\{\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} c_k \phi(\cdot-k)\ : \ c\in \ell^2\right\}$$
I like to know if $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ can be considered shift-invariant spaces.

I know that, if $f(x)\in PW_\pi$ (Paley-Wiener space), then
$$f(x)=\sum_n c_n \operatorname{sinc}(x-n)$$
and, since 
$$PW_\pi:=\{\text{f entire function}:\ |f(z)|\leq A e^{\pi |z|},\notag \\
\ z\in\mathbb C, \ \ f|_{\mathbb R}\in L^2(\mathbb R) \}$$

it should prove that $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is a shift-invariant space. Is it correct? What we can say for $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever told you that every $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ is equal to $\sum c_n sinc(x-n)$ lied.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I've edited post.

Comment: Did you mean to leave the second $L^2$ as is? Hard to see how $PW$ being a shift-invariant space is going to prove the same about $L^2(\Bbb R)$. Regarding $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$: By your definition asking whether this is a shift-invariant space makes no sense - if $f(x)$ is in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ there's no such thing as $f(x-5)$.

Comment: Thank you, now is a bit more clear.